# Tips on using Windows Identity Foundation with Visual Studio Express?

Tags: wif, visual-web-developer-2010

Is it possible to use the Windows Identity Foundation SDK with Visual Web Developer 2010 Express?

I understand that needing a professional version is a requirement, but if it's similar to other elements of the .net framework the tooling can normally be triggered from the command line.

I'm specifically looking to following the Azure Access Control tutorial: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/access-control/ and wondered if there are any workarounds to not having Visual Studio Professional+ installed?

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only gotcha in the steps are that Visual Studio Web Developer doesn't include the Add STS Reference menu option (in the "Configure Trust between ACS and Your ASP.NET Web Application" step).

That menu option simply launches the FedUtil.exe utlity that you'll find in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Identity Foundation SDK\v4.0.  So start that up, point it to the location of the web.config in the project you created, and the rest of the steps will work with no modification.

I gave it a shot on my own box, and it's working fine.  Good luck!